# git-checkout ant task (jgit) detached branch issue

Tags: java, git, ant, version-control, jgit

I am fairly new to git, and I have a problem. I have created couple branches on my git repository and whenever I use git-checkout ant task 
to move to a certain branch:

```
    <git-checkout src="./myrepo" branch="origin/mybranch" />
```

it shows the correct content of that branch in my repository but when I run `git branch` from the command line it says that its `"(detached from origin/mybranch)"`. After checking out I want to add some files to it, commit and push to remote with some custom ant tasks I wrote, but I'm not able to push because the branch I'm on is detached. How should I fix this?

Thank you for answers

Comment: I know nothing of the jgit/ant interaction here but obviously you're telling it to automatically check out `origin/mybranch`, vs manually check out `mybranch` (*not* the remote branch version in `origin/`).  Why?

Comment: Ok, my bad, it does the same with command line. But what I need to do to push my changes to remote at that stage?

Comment: When you ask git to check out a "remote branch", it literally can't: you are simply not allowed to be "on" a remote branch (git status says "on branch master" if you're on `master`, for instance; and you are not allowed to be "on remote branch origin/...").  So git puts you in "detached HEAD" mode instead: it checks out that specific commit, but if you make changes and commit them, they go on a temporary, unnamed branch.  If you want changes to go on a named branch, you must check out a (new or old) local branch by its name (you can use `-b` to create a new one, if that's the goal).

Comment: (I ran out of space above) The above is not really an *answer*, though, since I don't know anything about jgit-and-ant and (again) *why* you're moving to a specific commit identified by a remote-branch tip name.  It *is* possible to push from a detached HEAD to a remote, but it's unusual at least.  Whether there's some reason to do so with jgit-and-ant, I have no idea.

Comment: I needed an empty branch to commit some documentation files so i created one with `git checkout --orphan mybranch` and `git rm --cached -r .` then i added files needed and pushed (it worked fine) now i need to push some updated files on top, but i fail to do it.

Comment: It sounds like you want a local branch `mybranch` that tracks the remote `origin/mybranch` that you created on the remote when you pushed your local `mybranch`.

Comment: @torek Thank you! Finally, with your help, I was able to understand my prablem and make my task work!